# Tibbles vs Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, tibble

Hey just a general question,

I was wondering what was the difference between a tibble object and matrix object in R?

I normally use the "tidyverse" package and prefer to use tibbles, however when I tried to use the "glmnet" package, it requires its data to be a matrix, which I normally fix by using the

*as.matrix()* command on my tibble.

Was wondering if there was any difference in how we can operate on them, etc.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This might give you an idea. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/04/matrix-vs-data-frame-in-r/

Comment: Even matrix is sub-type of datafram where all datatype for all columns may only be same.